# Difference between paint() and repaint()

Tags: java, swing

I am a novice Java programmer and I'm finding quite some difficulty in figuring out the actual difference between the functioning of the `paint()` and `repaint()` method.
Also in some of the programs that I studied I found `paint()` and `repaint()` interchangeable.
Can someone please explain the difference? Thank you

Comment: _I found paint() and repaint() interchangeable_ then you studied very weird sources ;-) Please read some articles referenced in the swing tag wiki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to the `void paint(Graphics g)` method that is declared in the `Component` class:

This `paint` method is called automatically, whenever it is necessary to paint (parts of) the component. For example, when the window was obstructed by another window and then becomes visible again: The window manager will determine this, and call `paint` on the top level component (e.g. a Frame) and this call will make its way down to the actual "bottom" components (e.g. a Button). The `Graphics` object that is passed to this method is provided by the Window manager, and corresponds to the area on the screen where the component should be painted. (And this `Graphics` object is only valid during the `paint` method).

In contrast to that, `repaint()` just *triggers* a new painting process. It is telling the system: "Please call `paint` on this component as soon as possible". You can call this method manually. And you can call it freuqently: The calls to `repaint` are *coalesced*. That means that when you issue *many* calls to `repaint` in a short period of time, then these calls may be summarized and may eventually only trigger *one* call to `paint`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method should not be called directly as the javadoc states:

> Invoked by Swing to draw components. Applications should not invoke
>   paint directly, but should instead use the repaint method to schedule
>   the component for redrawing.

The [`repaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) method should be used instead if you want the component to be repainted (redrawn). The javadoc also refers to the following documentation: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

`paint()` get called automatically  at runtime. If you want to call `paint()` manually(again) then  `repaint()` is used.

Answer (score 0):

The **paint()** method contains instructions for painting the specific component.

The **repaint()** method, which can't be overridden, is more specific: it controls the update() to paint() process. You should call this method if you want a component to repaint itself or to change its look (but not the size).